# How to exclude specific script from preloader waiting to show the page

Tags: javascript, preloader, matomo

I am using PIWIK analytics software on [this page](http://www.adamvitovsky.cz/) and am having an issue with Bootstrap pre-loading the page. As you know, pre-loader won´t show you the whole webpage until fully loaded.

The problem is loading the PIWIK Javascript, It takes too long. It makes the page wait too long even it is already completely loaded and ready to use.

Is it possible to exclude waiting for this script to load?

Comment: You could load it with script that only fires after the preload is complete.